# findstr do not work in for command

Tags: batch-file

index file:index.txt

```
1
3
5
```

want to search file:file.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

My code:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\index.txt) do (
 findstr %%a C:\file.txt>nul
 if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo found %%a
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 if NOT errorlevel 1 echo found %%a
```

in place of

```
 if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo found %%a
```

The fundamental problem you have is related to `delayed expansion` (please search SO for references).

`errorlevel` is set for the result of the `findstr`, but within a `code block`, `%errorlevel%` will be replaced by the current value of `errorlevel` as it was when the `for` which governs the block was first encountered.

The syntax `if errorlevel n ...` means "if the errorlevel is *n* **or is greater than *n*** then ...

Since `findstr` will set `errorlevel` to `0` on "found" and `1` on "not found" then the required "show me if found" is `if not errorlevel 1`, ie. `errorlevel` is currently NEITHER 1 NOR greater than 1.